# How can I hide the header with navigation menu on just certain Digital Experience pages?

Tags: lwc-dom, header, digital-experience

I have an existing Digital Experience site that, for most pages, needs the header that includes the navigation menu and profile access. However, there are certain pages that are intended to be only accessed via a dedicated URL to perform certain actions and should be a "dead end", not allowing the user to navigate out to other site pages. These special pages would be accessed through specific links in a mobile app using OAuth 2 for the authentication.

While I have found ways to [completely remove the navigation menu and other header elements](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_theme_apply.htm&type=5) for whole digital experiences using theme settings, or could ensure the header is manually added to all pages except the ones of interest, or where I can have [variation in the page by audience](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5), I can't see how to just omit the header in select pages for the same user without making header management a headache.

Even CSS-based dodges don't look appropriate; theme-level CSS is, naturally, applied to all pages, while adding a custom LWC to the special pages to introduce page-specific CSS isn't going to work due to Shadow DOM scoping (I believe).

Could I use Light DOM tricks here (I get the feeling not)?

Is there an alternative to per-page headers that's clean and simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digital Experiences are based on a template. That template may provide various pages, but also layouts.

Opening the theme within the settings for the experience in the Experience Builder and selecting the Configure tab provides access to the theme layouts. It is here that you can create additional layouts and turn on and off layout features as permitted by the template's theme itself. Here's an example showing the creation of a new layout called "Alternative" using one of the provided theme layout components:

[image: Site's Theme's Layouts]

It should be noted that the options available depend on the layout component selected. This example is taken from the (Aura) Build Your Own template. Of course, it is also possible to implement new layout components if required (but that's not necessary in this case where the need was to simply remove the header and the layout component already provides for this). Either way, the layout component exposes any configurable options and, for this requirement, it's just a matter of unchecking "Show header".

Once a new layout is available and configured as desired, it is just a matter of selecting the page(s) from which the header is to be "removed", one at a time, viewing their settings, selecting "Override the default theme layout for this page" and choosing the required layout for the page, as illustrated below:

[image: Assigning a different layout to the page]